# Socket Listen for Events While Running Heartbeat

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, websocket

I am trying to setup a listener for socket events while concurrently sending a ping message in the background.

The `message received` events fire, but *only* after the next ping completes. There seems to be something blocking.

Here's a mockup of the code I'm running.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

message = "First Message"
ping = "ping"
url = 'www.socketurl.com'


async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    message = await websocket.recv()
    if message:
        print(message)

async def pingFunc(socket):
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    await socket.send(ping)

async def connect(uri):
    async with websockets.connect(uri,timeout=5) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(message) #send hello message that returns a few pieces of info
        while True: 
            await consumer_handler(websocket) #wait for messages and handle them
            await pingFunc(websocket) #keep the connection alive

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(
    connect(url)
)
```